# Java worker thread model

Tags: java, multithreading, worker

I want to implement a pool of worker threads That process input string and be in idle (no cpu) mode till I pass another input string.
I wrote bellow code for worker but get error

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

private String data =null;

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
    notify();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true){
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("data = " + data);
    }
}
```

and called

```
    Worker worker = new Worker();
    Thread thr = new Thread(worker);
    thr.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
     worker.setData("11111");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
     worker.setData("2222");
```

and How check the worker is busy.
Thanks

Comment: And you get which error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the wait() and notify() calls in a synchronized block.

```
static public class Worker implements Runnable {

    private String data = null;

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
        synchronized(this) {
            notify();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                synchronized(this) {
                    wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("data = " + data);
        }
    }
}
```